# Is it possible to create a if statement when setting an action input on GitHub Action?

Tags: github-actions

I have two steps in a GitHub workflow I want to join:

```
      - name: my action on environment a
        uses: myAction@v1
        if: github.ref != 'refs/heads/master'
        with:
          config 1: some config identical to other step
          config 2: some other config identical to other step
          environment: a
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
      - name: my action on environment b
        uses: myAction@v1
        if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/master'
        with:
          config 1: some config identical to other step
          config 2: some other config identical to other step
          environment: b
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

The only difference is the environment input. If master (use b environment) if not use a...

Is it possible to combine this value in a if-statement of some sort to avoid duplicating the step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. One way you can do it is to put the inputs into the environment manually at the top. The keys in `with` are capitalised and have `INPUT_` prefixed to them, then are set in the env. That is how [`core.getInput()`](https://github.com/actions/toolkit/blob/master/packages/core/src/core.ts#L69) picks them up.

You can add them in the `.yml` as config at the top - see [here](https://help.github.com/en/actions/configuring-and-managing-workflows/using-environment-variables).

Comment: I know that I can put the environment as an variable declared at the top of the  ´workflow.yaml´ file. but the question still remains... how can I combine two different values in an environment variable (or two different variables) to be injected into the environment in the the two different steps which only difference is the name of the branch being built?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a step to generate an `environment` variable as an output if the branch is the one you want or not, and then use it as input in your action.

**Here is an example of how it could be implemented:**

```yaml
   steps:
    - name: Check environment
      id: check
      run: |
        if [ ${{ github.ref }} != 'refs/heads/main' ]; then
          echo "IS NOT main branch"
          echo "environment a"
          echo "::set-output name=environment::a"
        else
          echo "IS main branch"
          echo "environment b"
          echo "::set-output name=environment::b"
        fi
      shell: bash
    - name: My action
      uses: myAction@v1
      with:
        config 1: some config identical to other step
        config 2: some other config identical to other step
        environment: ${{ steps.check.outputs.environment }}
      env:
        GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

A demo [workflow run](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/runs/4493259965?check_suite_focus=true) (printing the output) can be found here, I used [this workflow file](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/workflow-tester17.yml).